# Force throw jquery validator error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validate plugin for a ajax form.

To validate each field I have used  `data-rule-required="true"`.

Now I have four fields (read as 4 credit card fields). Now for all those fields separate am getting required error.

I want to combine their values and send throw a single error attached to the one erroneous field.

I have tried the following:

```
form3_validation.showErrors({
  "field_name1": "This is error"
});
```

But it is throwing an error for every field even if they are valid. I want to target only that field.

Comment: 4 credit card fields? are they all for entering the credit card number? why not just use one field as nearly every other site does?  (it will make your life easier, and not just for form validation...)

Comment: 16 digits divided into 4 each

Comment: ...which you then have to combine to get the credit card number to use it anywhere.  You are better off having one field where the visitor enters all 16 digits of their credit card number - people are used to that, and the side benefit is it simplifies your form validation.  You should also be aware that credit card numbers are not always 16 digits, and not always grouped in blocks of 4.

Comment: That is a client requirement and I am not trying to tinker with his design...but what I want is how to fire/throw error for a particular field, not for every field.

Comment: Ah - client constraint - that changes the whole thing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **remove** `data-rule-required="true"` from these fields.

The way this is normally handled is with [the `require_from_group` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/).  This method allows you to treat several fields as one.  Combine it with [the `groups` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) to get one single message for all fields in this group.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        groups: {
            creditcard: "foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4"
        },
        rules: {
            // some other rules here
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertBefore(element);
        }
    });

    var myGroup = $('.mygroup');

    myGroup.each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            require_from_group: [4, myGroup],
            messages: {
                require_from_group: "credit card number required"
            }
        });
    });

});
```

- All four fields share a class name called `mygroup` that is used to
  identify these.
- The `require_from_group` method is part of [the
  `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.js), so don't forget to include this
  too.
- I used the `.rules()` method simply to avoid having to define the
  same rule four separate times within the `rules` object of the
  `.validate()` method.

**DEMO: [jsfiddle.net/9sxt9u1a/](https://jsfiddle.net/9sxt9u1a/)**

---

The above answers your question as per your client's requirements.  However, the `additional-methods.js` file already contains several ready-to-use rules for credit card fields.  It would be cleaner and easier to implement than having four boxes of numbers in a grouping.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: OP clarified that the user was about the jQuery Validate plugin, not generic data-validation in JS. Leaving this answer up because it is not totally relevant but may still be helpful to someone.

You can add an identified for every field (e.g., data-attribute `data-field-id`), and then go through each of the input fields and report an error if one is empty.

This will go through each input box and report specifically which one is the problem, because they are all marked by identifiers.

```js
var fields = $(".field");
$("button[type=submit]").click(function() {
  var error = false;
  fields.each(function() {
    if(error) {
      return;
    }
    if($(this).val() === "") {
      error = "Error: required field " + $(this).data("field-id") + " is blank.";
    }
  });
  if(error) {
    alert(error);
  } else {
    alert("All good!");
  }
});
```

```css
.field {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="field" data-field-id="1" type="number">-
<input class="field" data-field-id="2" type="number">-
<input class="field" data-field-id="3" type="number">-
<input class="field" data-field-id="4" type="number">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: The question was about jquery validation :( not a custom script

Comment: @Alice My bad. I thought you just meant *data validation* in JS when you mentioned "validate." I edited your question and added the jquery-validate tag to make this more clear.